# generate unique random id when click on link php

Tags: php

I need to create unique id on user's every click link.
Let I have a code

```
<a class="popup-text" href="examplelink&aff_sub=<?php echo $up_id; ?>" data-toggle="modal">Upto Rs.10000 Cashback LED TVs 
+ Get additional upto Rs. 4 Cashback from afft</a>
```

when user click on that link `$up_id` should be automatically generated. `$up_id` should change every time when user click on that link.
`$up_id` comes from following code

```
<?php 
$up_id=md5(uniqid(rand(), true)); 
?>
```

but I am getting same id every time.

Comment: take md5(timestamp), it will be unique.

Comment: Please check again it is not possible @nehaJ

Comment: It happens because php is static, it's loaded just one time. To get a different id, you need to reload de page. The solution is update the id using javascript or make a ajax request and get a new id every time you click on the link... And no one understood the real problem.

Comment: ok @lago. Do u have any idea how should I update it using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of PHP you can generate random number by using javascript, tryout following code:

```
<a class="popup-text" href="examplelink" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?&aff_sub='+Math.floor((Math.random()*1000)+1);return false;" data-toggle="modal">Upto Rs.10000 Cashback LED TVs 
         + Get additional upto Rs. 4 Cashback from afft</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this would be, get current timestamp and take `md5()` of thst

```
$up_id = md5(current time stamp);
```

Comment: `md5(uniqid(rand(), true))` already generate a random string based on the time. See [the doc](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php).

Answer (score -1):

You can easily achieve this with the following function:

```
function random_string($length)
{
   $string = "";
   $chars = "abcdefghijklmanopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $size = strlen($chars);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
       $string .= $chars[rand(0, $size - 1)];
   }
   return $string; 
}
```

Here you first generate an empty string, then you define a string with all chars you want. After you also counted the numbers of chars you can start with filling your new string. You just use a for-loop to do this. Everytime the loopcontent is called, there is one random char (from your $char) added to your empty string.

You use this function (for example if you want to store your ID in a variable) by simply typing:

```
$password = rand_string(15) //the number specified in brackets is the amount of characters in your password
```

So with this function, you can just always generate a random string (in your case, a unique ID).

Let me know, if you're experiencing any issues.

Comment: `md5(uniqid(rand(), true))` already generate a random string.